# Extracting info from grib files

Tags: python, dataframe, grib

I'm trying the following: convert a grib file with historical info of temperatures by hour of a specific region into csv,

I'm following this documentation: https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/CKB/How+to+convert+GRIB+to+CSV

I would like to convert my grib file into csv or similar and join the data of temperature, hour and date with my dataframe,

As you can read in the link doing:

```
grib_get_data madrid_2014_2022.grib > madrid_2014_2022.csv
```

I get a .csv file with only Lat, Long and temperature values, but I would like to also have the columns: dataDate and stepRange,

I haven't succeed looking for solutions after googling, so I would like to ask if anyone could give me a hint to achieve a solution,

I'm using python,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use Python xarray to read, slice, filter, modify and write to csv all you need: https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/examples/ERA5-GRIB-example.html

Answer (score 0):

You can extract data from GRIB files using the standalone program [CDO](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo)